# Office document not working in ACTION_VIEW intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open an office document with any other office reader using Intent.ACTION_VIEW but it only works in Google Sheets or Google Docs, with other applications like for example Polaris Office or any other, it doesn't work at all.
Here is the code that I am wrote:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File mFile = new File("folder", Integer.toString(myFile.hashCode()));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(mFile), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: "but it only works in Google Sheets or Google Docs" -- it does not work with those apps either. `new File("folder", Integer.toString(myFile.hashCode()))` does not point anywhere useful.

Comment: the "folder" parameter was just a generic example

Comment: the correct is File mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sheet.xlsx");

Comment: I'm still with the problem